# Cannot find my .odt file (Saved it from .doc)

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-word

A big Unfortunate thing has happened and I am really freaking out at the moment :(.

My PC has dual boots (windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.0).
Firstly I have started working on my assignment in MS WORD (.doc) in windows 10 and then opened it in Ubuntu (LibreOffice) and made almost all changes to the file and nearly finished all of my assignment in ubuntu and finally saved the file in .odt format (I am pretty sure I have saved it in documents in ubuntu).Then I have closed my file after saving changes.

AND NOW I cannot see my assignment file which I have done in my documents. All I can see is the previous word (.doc) assignment.

I am really afraid that I lost my file. I have tried various things from the google and didn't quite know exactly what to do recover my file now. 
Is there any way that I could recover my file?

Any help is much appreciated and my assignment is due tomorrow morning :( I am freaking out now :( Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it appear in **File > Recent Documents** in LibreOffice Writer?

Comment: @pomsky I could see the file name there in Recent Documents, and when I tried clicking it, it says that the file does not exist :( I have no idea why :(

Comment: Right-click this shortcut, go to Properties, you will see where it was saved.

Comment: Accidental deletion? Did you by any chance save it in another drive which is now unmounted? For example USB flash drive or another partition.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was not distroyed.

From ubuntu open a terminal by pressing `ctrl` + `alt` + `t`. Running `find ~/ -atime 0 -iname *odt` will find files in your home dir less than 24 hours with a name ending in odt. Change the dir to the path where you think the file is. Then change the location or time or name.

If the file seems to have been deleted see [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

If the file was not saved but accidentally lost LibreOffice should have offered to recover the file. Also check the modification date of the doc version it may have been where the autosave ended up.